# Is it possible to use update handle XML in a theme, used in multiple modules layout XML?

Tags: magento2, layout, layout-update, update-handle

Within a Magento 2 theme, given an XML layout file such as the following, named for example, ***remove_header.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

How can I use `<update handle="remove_header"/>` in any module layout XML files in the theme?

The goal is to be able have the following layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <update handle="remove_header" />
    </body>
</page>
```

in both ***theme-stackoverflow/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml*** and ***theme-stackoverflow/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml***

Without being able to that, I'd have to place ***remove_header.xml*** in ***theme-stackoverflow/Magento_Catalog/layout/*** and ***theme-stackoverflow/Magento_Cms/layout/*** which basically negates the point of having the update in a seperate XML file referenced via `<update />`

There's not an option to have a directory such as ***theme-stackoverflow/frontend/layout/*** or similar that I've seen. I tried placing the referred to XML file in Magento_Theme so at ***theme-stackoverflow/Magento_Theme/layout/remove_header.xml*** and using `<update />` exactly as shown above. It doesn't work.

So is this even possible or in this case, would you have to duplicate the layout XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, turns out placing the referred to XML file at ***theme-stackoverflow/Magento_Theme/layout/remove_header.xml*** does actually work. It was my placement of `<update handle/>` that was at fault. The layout update won't take place unless the node is top-level, so not a child of the `<body>` node.

Changing the second block of XML in the question to the following allows the solution to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- Moved to here... -->
    <update handle="remove_header" />
    <body>
         <!-- ..from here -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Will accept this answer in 2 days when I'm able to. If anyone has a more elegant solution though it would be great to hear about it.